# How can I get the member columns of a primary key in SQL Server, sorted by priority in order query result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, information-schema

In SQL Server I got some tables with primary key with more than one column. I using this query to get the columns of the primary key in a table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = 'Code Field Information'
```

This query returns three columns, members of the primary key. But when I execute a query in table 'Code Field information', without Order clause, the sort in result is not the same than I get with the query of above. It's possible get the columns of the primary key in order of sort priority?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: You want to `ORDER BY`?  If that's the case you put `ORDER BY <columnname> ASC`  to sort in ascending order or `DESC` to sort in descending order.

Comment: Without using "Order", SQL does not guarantee order the result. I mean, the same query can be returned result different order at different times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this way returns the result ordering the members of primary key for his priority in order the results.

```
SELECT i.name AS IndexName, OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
    ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
    WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 AND OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID)  = 'Code Field Information'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your result to guarantee that it will remain the same every time. I see that you have column called `Constraint_Type` which from your example I assume is primary key and is unique. Any value that is unique (and will remain so over time) is a good candidate.

If that is true we will use that column to sort the result.

So your query should look like (it's not best query syntax but it's closest to yours)

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = 'Code Field Information'
ORDER BY Constraint_Type
```

You can also use `ORDER BY Constraint_Type DESC` for reverse order. Now your results will come as same no matter how many times you query. Ofc, if your data is not changed, that is.

If you plan using this often and need it to be quick, you should think about adding index to that table for that column.